# Naming a sublime completion?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3

I'm wondering if it's possible to "name" a sublime completion so that the name shows up in the auto complete box.  With snippets, you can do this by adding a `description`, but I tried adding that (and `name`) to the completion with no luck.

To show what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

The first option is from a snippet with `<description>console.log snippet</description>` set.

The second option is a completion:

```
{ "trigger" : "cl"  , "description" : "console.log", "contents" : "console.log( ${10} );" }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `\t` after the trigger text. However, there is a [bug](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/1061) where buffer completions get blocked when using this feature.

```
{
    "scope": "source.php",
    "completions": [
        {
            "trigger": "trigger_text\tdescription_text",
            "contents":"contents_text"
        }
    ]
}
```